# TShark pcap filter command possibly simplified?

Tags: command-line, scripting, tshark, pcap

Object: to find the IP addresses of HTTP servers in a pcap file with a specific header string. Can or should the `-l` option to flush be used?

One way: the following was done but am wondering if it can be shortened. If this question is too broad, please advise.

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e http.server > name.txt &&
  cat name.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | grep "xxx_xxx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a count of the src IP addresses in the frames that also contain an HTTP response with a `Server` header containing `xxx_xxx`, you could do:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e ip.src 'http.server contains "xxx_xxx"' |
  sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

See [the doc](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html) for the syntax of wireshark display filters.

Some of `tshark`'s own analysis reports (with `-z`) might also be useful to you like:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -z http_srv,tree -2R 'http.server contains "xxx_xxx"'
```

```
tshark -r file.pcap -z hosts,ip -2R 'http.server contains "xxx_xxx"'
```

```
tshark -r file.pcap -z conv,ip -2R 'http.server contains "xxx_xxx"'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. There was no need to write to a file and then to cat that file. I was sure this was the case but after a dozen attempts, couldn't find a way to eliminate the extra step. The single/double quotes confuse(d) me. Can't remember what the previous iteration of -2R is. Nicely done.

Comment: For my purposes, the most significant is the -z with hosts,ip 2R but all were in many ways very relevant. I will try to combine suggestions 3 and 4.